# Specific toSquare function in C

Tags: c++, c, macros

I'm dealing with very strange task for my university. The goal is to write an implementation for function which works as presented below :

```
int z = 3;
toSquare(2);
toSquare(6);
toSquare(Incr(z));
toSquare(2+4);       
/* result : 
2 to square is 4.
6 to square is 36.
Incr(z) to square is 16.
2+4 to square is 16.
*/
```

I was thinking about using macros, as you see in line 10. '2+4' was printed against expected(?) 6 so it may be done by using macro # option but I don't know how to deal with that toSquare(2+4) and result is 2+4 to square is 16. Thanks for all ideas and solutions !
Cheers

Comment: Who says that 2+4 is printed? That´s just a comment. toSquare shouldn´t print anything. What the calling code does is none of your concern when writing the function.

Comment: Close-voters: Maybe read again. It´s perfectly clear what is confusing him.

Comment: I could believe that `toSquare(2+4)` gives 14...

Comment: The fact that `toSquare(6)` should yield `36`, but `toSquare(2+4)` is supposed to return `16` makes me think that it's just a typo. You have no way to distinguish the two at runtime. Moreover, a good compiler will almost always fold constant expressions (i.e. replace `2+4` with `6`). Drop a line to your instructor.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo It turns out it's not a type. Take a look at my answer...

Comment: @EitanT yeah, I upvoted it. Good catch. I guess the instructor wanted students to realize how dangerous the preprocessor can be if used incorrectly. To people who voted to close: _"unclear what you're asking"_, seriously? At most, this falls under the old _"too localized"_.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer involves the following two principles:

1. Use macros for stringification: this is what the `#` preprocessor operator is for.
2. Use sneaky parentheses for manipulating argument expansion. Note that `(2+4) * 2+4` equals 16. Therefore, enclose the first operand with parentheses, but not the second one!

This yields the following macro:

```
#define toSquare(x)    \
    std::cout << #x << " to square is " << (x) * x << std::end;
```

Here's a [working example](http://ideone.com/2J0fO5).

Answer (score -3):

Solution in C using a macro `TOSQUARE`:

```
#define TOSQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
int main()
{
   int z = 3;
   TOSQUARE(2);
   TOSQUARE(6);
   TOSQUARE(Incr(z));
   z = TOSQUARE(2+4); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It anyway does not produce any output.